# jquery get select option value and then add parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add on to the value "&fullpage=true"

```
<select name="navMenu" onchange="go(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="-">Select</option>
<option value="page.html&amp;nyo=0" class="ccbnLnk">All</option>
<option value="page.html&amp;nyo=0" class="ccbnLnk">IR</option>
<option value="page.html&amp;nyo=0" class="ccbnLnk">Product</option>
</select>
```

I'm guessing it would be something like this?

```
$('select option').attr(val + "&fullpage=true");
```

Comment: You are guessing?  Do you mean you haven't tried? If you did, did it work?  If not, what did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but you needed to iterate over all the option elements and then make the change like:

```
$('select option').each(function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val() + "&fullpage=true");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bnJG8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each of the element using the each function

```
$('select option').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('value') + "&fullpage=true");
});
```